# Basis using Matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Show that the vectors $(1,2,1), (2,1,0), (1,-1,2)$ form a basis of $\mathbb R^3$.

I want to use the matrix method where I set up a $3 \times 3$ matrix where each vector is a row. I reduced to echelon form and obtained:

$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 & 1\\
2 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & -1 & 2\\
\end{bmatrix} =
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 & 1\\
0 & 1 & \frac{2}{3} \\
0 & 0 & 1 
\end{bmatrix}
$

My notes say: Consider the matrix $A ∈ M_{mn}(F)$ and let $R$ be an echelon form of
$A$ obtained by elementary row operations. Then $row(A) = row(R)$ and the rows of
R are a basis for $row(A)$.

Does that mean {$(1,2,1)$,$(0,1,\frac{2}{3})$,$(0,0,1)$} is a basis of of $\mathbb R^3$?

But to answer the question, no zon-zero rows mean that the vectors $(1,2,1), (2,1,0), (1,-1,2)$ are linearly independent and span $\mathbb R^3$ so form a basis ?

Comment: yes, the rank of the matrix is 3 so it spans all of R^3.

Comment: @TigerBlood Thank you. Can you tell me whether my question starting with "Does that mean...." is right or wrong ?

Comment: Look at the following link, there is a clear example: under the Basis section:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row_and_column_spaces

Comment: @NoChance I think I messed up originally because the vectors should be the columns of my matrix ? Or does it not matter ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that $\{(1,2,1),(0,1,\frac{2}{3}),(0,0,1)\}$ is a basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$.
Performing row operations is equivalent to adding scaled version of other vectors in the list of vectors, or switching the order of the list of vectors. The row vectors after row operation is a linear combination of row vectors.

If the echelon form of a matrix \begin{bmatrix}-&v_1^T&-\\&\dots&\\-&v_n^T&-\end{bmatrix} has as much pivot as there are rows, then that means even after switching order of vectors, the last vector $v_n$ cannot be written as a linear combination of $v_1,\dots,v_{n-1}$. Which is equivalent to saying every vector in the list is not in the span of the other vectors, which implies linear independence.

So if the echelon form is at full rank, then the original list of vector is linear independent. If provided the list has length equal to the dimension, then the linear independent list of vectors form a basis.

Comment: Thanks I will accept your answer. So $\{(1,2,1),(0,1,\frac{2}{3}),(0,0,1)\}$ is a basis of $\mathbb R^3$, but is it also a basis for $\{(1,2,1),(2,1,0),(1,-1,2)}$, since that's what the theorem in my notes that I posted in my opening post stated ?

Comment: Yes, the original list of vector is also a basis, this is address in the question.

Comment: Thanks, but I meant is $\{(1,2,1),(0,1,\frac{2}{3}),(0,0,1)\}$ a basis of $\{(1,2,1),(2,1,0),(1,-1,2)\}$?

Comment: Do you mean the span of  $\{(1,2,1),(2,1,0),(1,−1,2)\}$? Notice that the original and the new list of vectors are all basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$, so they all span $\mathbb{R}^3$ by definition.
So indeed $\{(1,2,1),(0,1,\frac{2}{3}),(0,0,1)\}$ spans  $span\{(1,2,1),(2,1,0),(1,−1,2)\}=\mathbb{R}^3$. By linear independence, the list of spanning vectors is also a basis.

Comment: Perfect, that was exactly what I meant.

Comment: Final question - when creating the matrix, I placed the vectors in rows. If I placed them in columns, would I get the same conclusion ? As in, does it make a difference if I place the vectors in rows or columns ?

Comment: Short answer, if you want to put vectors in rows, then use row operation. If you put them as column vectors, then do column operations.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pjMwZPo8UvQ In this video he used row operations though ?

Comment: This is due to the fact that the rank (number of pivots) of a matrix is the same as its transpose.
Notice that performing row operation on a matrix is the same as performing column operation on transpose, then finally taking transpose.
So no matter which operation you perform, the pivots of the matrix remains the same.
He uses this fact to show that the list is not independent.

Comment: Okay I think I understand everything now. Thanks for answering all my questions.